# Converting from angular I to Angular 2

Tags: angularjs, angular

I'm trying to fully understand the concept in converting code from angular I to II. In using the following small snippet of code:

```
 <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
        <input type="text" ng-model="width" /><br />
        <input type="text" ng-model="height" /><br />

        <p>The result is: </p>{{width * height /2}};
    </div>

    <script>
        var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
        app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
            $scope.width = 44;
            $scope.height = 22;

        });
    </script>
```

How would I convert the above from angular 1 to angualr 2? I read that it consist of replacing the directives with components. Could I get a demonstration using the snippet I provided? Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Angular has a completely new tooling and has a fairly complex (albeit robust) system to allow subscoping components, so it's a bit more involved than just replacing snippets. I personally don't know enough about Angular to write a comprehensive step-by-step answer for you though, sorry.

Comment: StackOverflow is not a tutorial service. You should start with [Angular Developer Guide - Tutorial](https://angular.io/tutorial). Then come back to StackOverflow for specific questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know it's been a downvoted question but I would still like to provide you an answer.

For the above html, you can create something similar in angular 2 as:

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NgForm } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  onSubmit(f: NgForm) {
    console.log(f.value);  // { first: '', last: '' }
    console.log(f.valid);  // false
  }
}
```

An html file with form:

**app.component.html**

```
<div class="container">
  <form #f="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(f)" novalidate>
    <input name="first" ngModel required #first="ngModel">
    <input name="last" ngModel>
    <button>Submit</button>
  </form>

  <p>First name value: {{ first.value }}</p>
  <p>First name valid: {{ first.valid }}</p>
  <p>Form value: {{ f.value | json }}</p>
  <p>Form valid: {{ f.valid }}</p>
  <p>The result is : {{f.value.first * f.value.last}}</p>
</div>
```

To render this `app` component, you'll add below tag in `index.html`:

```
<body>
  <app-root>Loading...</app-root>
</body>
```

I have provided the answer in a `form` as it seemed more relevant example to take.

You can see:

1. There is not `ng-controller` now, it has component which will have the controller logic in it.
2. There is no `$scope`

I have taken example from [Angular.io website which has good documentation](https://angular.io/api/forms/NgModel)

I would strongly suggest you to start your Angular journey from [this book which is free and it really really good](https://codecraft.tv/assets/books/angular-from-theory-to-practice.pdf)

You can also get some simple examples over [my git for Angular](https://github.com/shashankvivek/Angular4)

**Side Note** : The angular has no similarity with `AngularJS 1.X` so I strongly suggest you to understand `component` based architecture of Angular2 and start rewriting codes in that way.

Comment: Shashank Vivek - Thank you for your feedback and the resources provided, all was very helpful.

Comment: @user1724708 : Happy to help you. I also face this on SO sometimes where I ask for proper direction and I get downvotes. Cheers ;)